# Accessing 2d array with pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, arrays, pointer-arithmetic

I have an array `A[n][n]` how come i can access it like this: `*A+i*blockSize*dimenson`? Doesn't that translate to `A[i*blockSize*n]`?

How can this be if `i*blockSize*n` is a number bigger than n? I was thinking that it works because 2d arrays in C are really just one contiguous piece of memory. But, that doesn't change the fact that i can't code `A[i*blockSize*n][j] = something` without getting a run-time error.

So why is `*A+i*blockSize*dimenson` ok but, not `A[i*blockSize*n]`

I hope this question makes sense to someone who is an expert in C..

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't that translate to `A[i * blockSize * n]`

No, it doesn't what you have is<sup>1</sup>

```
*A + i * blockSize * dimenson
```

is actually equivalent to

```
A[0] + i * blockSize * dimension
```

You need to read about [*operator precedence*](https://cs50.harvard.edu/resources/cppreference.com/operator_precedence.html), the correct equivalent expression is

```
*(A + i * blockSize * dimenson)
```

but that is not necessary because it makes the code harder to read without giving you any benefit at all.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Please use surrounding spaces for operators so that it's easy to distinguish between operators and operands.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

First:

```
*(A+i*blockSize*dimenson)
```

Translates into:

```
A[i*blockSize*dimenson]
```

And you simply can't do:

```
A[i*blockSize*n][j] = something
```

if `i*blockSize*n` is bigger than `n`, because you will get out of the bounds of the array you allocated, which is of size n by n.

But you can do:

```
A[i][j]
```

as:

```
B[i*n+j]
```

if you declare B as unidimensional array pointing to A, for example:

```
int A[n][n];
int * B = (int *)A;
```

Comment: *if you declare `B` as unidimensional array pointing to `A`* How would you do that? And this `*(A + i * blockSize * dimenson)` is not in the posted examples.

Comment: I just added parenthesis to be clear of operator precedence, which is the same example as `*A+i*blockSize*dimenson`. I also edited how to declare that.

Comment: It's not the same, please read my answer. The `*` ([*dereference operator*](https://cs50.harvard.edu/resources/cppreference.com/operator_precedence.html)) has the highest precedence among all the operators involved in the expression. Also, although the second part is technically correct (it would work correctly) there is no such thing as *declare `B` as a unidimensional array **pointing** to `A`.*